# Comparing Dates in Django

Tags: django, date, date-comparison

I need to compare a date field in my bookings table with today's date. I am trying to loop through all bookings dates and if the date is less than today's date date to change a field status to "Completed"

I keep getting the below error

"TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'"

I have tried to research this but I am unable to resolve the issue.

Below is my code.

Model.(ASPBookings)

```
booking_date = models.DateField()
```

View

```
date_today = (datetime.datetime.now())
date_stripped = date_today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

asp_date_data = ASPBookings.objects.all()

for booking in asp_date_data:
    print (booking.booking_date)
    if booking.booking_date < date_stripped:
       booking.status == 'Completed'
       booking.save()
```

I have checked the output of the fields and after stripping the time the dates appear the same. eg.

ASPBookings field dates
2021-05-27
2021-06-24
2021-06-15

Today's date
2021-06-09

Thanks in advance for any help I can get on this.

Comment: `strftime` will give you a string

Comment: also remove the extra `=`: `booking.status = 'Completed'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear, it means you can't compare a `date` object (`booking.booking_date`'s type) with a string (`date_stripped`'s type). Try this:

```py
date_today = datetime.datetime.now().date() # use this instead of strftime

asp_date_data = ASPBookings.objects.all()

for booking in asp_date_data:
    print (booking.booking_date)
    if booking.booking_date < date_stripped:
       booking.status == 'Completed'
       booking.save()
```

Comment: Thanks you hldev and bdbd, appreciate the help. That worked.